# xsl tags not showing apostrophe character

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the xsl below:

```xml
<xsl:copy-of select="$value-of-variable"/>
```

When I run it the output is: `My dog&apos;s big`

I tried:

```xml
<xsl:copy-of select="$value-of-variable" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

but it didn't make any difference.

The output should be: `My dog's big`

Comment: What is the `xsl:output method`, `xml`, `html`, plain `text`? In XML or HTML output an `&apos;` will be interpreted the same way as a plain `'`.

Comment: Please provide a simple way to reproduce the problem - see: [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The `disable-output-escaping` attribute is not allowed on element `xsl:copy-of`. If (as it seems) your variable contains:

```
"My dog&amp;apos;s big"
```

then the instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$yourVariable" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

will return:

```
"My dog&apos;s big"
```

which is semantically equal to:

```
"My dog's big"
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, all versions of the specifications allow an apostrophe to be serialized as `&apos;`, though they do not of course require it. There is no mechanism in the W3C specs to control this. Of course, if the content is read using a conformant XML parser, then `'` and `&apos;` are completely interchangeable.

If you're producing output for a recipient that is fussy about this, and which can't be changed, then you might try putting the XML through a different serializer. You haven't said which product you are using.